# SinonJS only allowed to mock methods that exist?

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

I am using SinonJS to do a lot of mocking - is there any sort of configuration that will make it so that I am only allowed to mock methods that exist?

Comment: You could explicitly test for a method before defining the mock. If you find you're doing this a lot, create a simple utility function for it.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow, but can you even mock a non-existent method? I don't have that much experience with SinonJS, but isn't it always the case that you either "spy" on whether a certain method was called, or you "stub" a method in order to control the return value. Either way you always work with existing methods.

Comment: if you have a lot of mocking in each test, it means you have tightly coupled code. Remember, a lot of mocking is design smell.